# barcode scanner using phonegap plugin without using the barcode library?

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on phonegap android application. this is entirely new to me. I want develop an application with barcode scanner. that too it might uses the intent call. That means the barcode intent is called from the java code and once the scanning over the result should be displayed in HTML page.

Comment: have you tried the below solution??

Comment: @dhaval: Thank U so much..  today only I have tried, got the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code from a phonegap plugin works as expected:

```
    public PluginResult execute(String arg0, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
    //  intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        ctx.startActivityForResult(this, intent, 0);

        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            Log.i("Cordova", "result " + resultCode);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                Log.i("Cordova", "contents " + contents + ", format " + format);
                // Handle successful scan
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
                Log.i("Cordova", "scan cancelled");
            }
        }
    }
```

Tested with Cordova 1.7 and Android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Just go [to](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner)  and follow the instructions in the readme file.

After adding this to your project you can use something like

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result) {
        alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                  "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                  "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                  "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
);
```

to do the scan.